# Immediately receive saved item(s) on calling DbContext.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, savechanges

I would like to implement two custom `SaveChanges()` methods in my `DbContext`, where those return the saved entity/entities when calling `SaveChanges()` instead of the number of affected rows.

I am using EF Core 2.0.

What would be the best way to accomplish that?

Best regards

Comment: Note that you can't literally _override_ a method just by changing the return type, so you'll need to use a different method name and/or add parameters. What if multiple objects were updated - what would your return type be?

Comment: My mistake, I will edit my question. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core returns the objects on calling `context.Add()/Update()/Remove()` etc. Therefore i can retrieve them this way.